# Keep search results after sort in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a sortable AND searchable list.

Both functions work on their own, but when I search and then try to sort the results, I get all elements again and not only the searched ones.

My view looks like below:

```
<%= form_tag(user_subnets_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Subnets" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>



<% if @subnets.blank? and params[:search]%>
  <h4>There are no subnets containing the term "<%= params[:search] %>".</h4>
<% else %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "CIDR", "CIDR" %></th>
    </tr>

    <% @subnets.each do |subnet| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= subnet.name %></td>
        <td><%= subnet.CIDR %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_subnet_path(@user, subnet) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_subnet_path(@user, subnet) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

  </table>
<% end %>
```

The corresponding controller

```
...
def index
  #TODO: keep params after submit -> Search + order at once
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @subnets = @user.subnets.order(sort_column+ ' ' +sort_direction).search(params[:search])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data Subnet.to_csv(@subnets) }
  end
end
...

private

def subnet_params
  params.require(:subnet).permit(:name, :CIDR)
end

def sort_column
  if params[:id]
    Device.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "IP"
  else
    Subnet.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

And the `search` function from the model

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where("subnets.name LIKE ? OR subnets.CIDR LIKE ?",  "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

And the `application_helper`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
  end
end
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

I am running Rails 5.1.4

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your helper class where from `sortable` come

Comment: I added the `application_helper` code

Comment: Try applying the order method after you call the search method in your index action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be ok all are right now just little change to the application helper `sortable` method and last line

Try to the following

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, request.query_parameters.merge({sort: column, direction: direction})
end
```

Hope it helps